# bluetooth keyboard connected but not working

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, wacom

I've been trying to get my wacom bluetooth keyboard to work with my wacom companion 2.  It pairs and connects fine, and the connection looks good, but it won't type anything.  I'm running 16.04 lts.  This keyboard works on other devices.  Please help.

Comment: Have you tried running `xev` to check to see if it's transmitting keycodes to the system?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what keycods are, but when I ran xev I saw data appear in my terminal with cellwriter and Onboard input, but nothing from my keyboard.

Comment: My apologies but I am unfamiliar with the hardware you are attempting to use. Perhaps providing the model numbers of your wacom bluetooth keyboard &  wacom companion 2 would help us help you find clarity for this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your Wacom kernel driver:

```
http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Input-wacom
```

and your Wacom X driver:

```
http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Xf86-input-wacom
```

More likely it is your X driver in this case so you may want to try that first.

Comment: I've updated both to no avail.